# Oracle client mismatch

Tags: vb.net, oracle, oracle11g

I have taken a code from another environment onto my local system. The code is written in VB.NET and the backend technology is oracle 11g. While debugging the code in the local environment , I am unable to connect to the oracle database. The inner exception states 'The provider is not compatible with the version of Oracle client'. What should be the suggested action items to debug the issue and correct it?

Comment: I suppose you need to make sure the provided name matches. Without more information, I don't see how we can help.

Comment: Hi Blackwood, The exact error is '{"The provider is not compatible with the version of Oracle client"}. I am working on VB.NET with Oracle 11 g as the backend technology and I have Oraclient 11g_home1 in my system. I copied the code from a different system onto my system and tried to run it but the code would throw exception while establishing a connection with the database.

Comment: Editing your question to include that information would be a good start. However, I don't see how we are supposed to know what versions of the Oracle client and Oracle provider you are using. Please remember that we only know the information that you post.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestions.  I have very little knowledge about oracle connectivity. Could you please help me out with the list of actions I should perform to get to the root cause of the issue or to find out a workaround?